# exporting an object that's new each time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So I want a file to be exporting an object, but it should have a different reference each time. Currently, the single export shares the same reference (two files importing, if one changes, so does the other). I've even tried doing an IIFE.

export.js

```
export const pagination =
    (function ()
    {
        let page_lengths =
            live
                ? [
                    5,
                    10,
                    15,
                    20,
                    25
                ]
                : [
                    1,
                    2,
                    3,
                    4,
                    5
                ]
        return {
            page:
                1,
            page_length:
                page_lengths[0],
            page_lengths,
            total:
                0,
        }
    })()
```

import.js

```
import {
    pagination,
} from "export.js"
```

Comment: Sure, you've created a Singleton. Remove the IIFE wrapper.

Comment: You can turn this IIFE into a class and export it, at the import file you import it and create a new instance of the class

Comment: @RandyCasburn I think I'm not trying to create a singleton? I want each import to create a new object.

Comment: But your are creating a singleton. Do what @RamonPortela suggests. It is the correct approach to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, just don't invoke immediately:

**export.js**

```
export const pagination =
(function ()
{
    let page_lengths =
        live
            ? [
                5,
                10,
                15,
                20,
                25
            ]
            : [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4,
                5
            ]
    return {
        page: 1,
        page_length: page_lengths[0],
        um: page_lengths.slice(), // <-- clone the array
        total: 0,
    }
}); // <--- no invoke here
```

**import.js**

```
import {
    pagination,
} from "export.js"

var foo = pagination(); // invoke here
```

Comment: yeah I just went with the simple method execution